# edge driver is not getting installed using robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

We are using Python robot framework automation. Is it possible to download and install edge driver automatically while script run based on the version passed as parameter?We are using selenium 3.14 , robot framework selenium library 4.5.0 and python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Installation of any webdriver must be done before running tests, because it requires to have prepared the environment variable PATH and proper execution permissions for the webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to download and install edge driver automatically while script run based on the version passed as parameter?

Answer- YES

For that you need to install driver manager using - `pip install webdriver-manager`

Then use the below imports -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
```

You can use the python function as keyword in robot framework something like given below. Where `96.0.1054.43` parameter is the version of edge driver. And this function is written in lets say - `drivermanager.py` file.

```
def get_chromedriver_path():
    driver_path = EdgeChromiumDriverManager("96.0.1054.43").install()
    print(driver_path)
    return  driver_path
```

You can import this(`drivermanager.py`) library in your testsuite using command - `Library     drivermanager.py`. This function will be treated as keyword when executed.

Testsuite will have testcase as

```
Open Chrome Browser
    [Documentation]      To create chrome browser instance with specific profile

    ${chromedriver_path}=   drivermanager.Get Chromedriver Path
```

Here `${chromedriver_path}` variable holds the driver path. and the driver stored in the cache.

Screenshot of Executions -

[image]

References - 1. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
2. https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

Answer (score 0):

You can use msedgedriver library to install the version of edgedriver that your browser supports.

do

```
pip install msedgedriver
```

to install this library

then do

```
import msedgedriver
from selenium import webdriver  

msedgedriver.install() #you will notice a file named msedgedriver.exe is downloaded in your directory

Driver = webdriver.Edge('msedgedriver.exe')#msedgedriver was installed by above command
```